# Como somar valores de um csv usando Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Tenho um arquivo csv parecido com este, com todos os informações de todos os municípios do Brasil (encurtei o csv para não ficar muito extenso):

```
ESTADO,MUNICIPIO,HABITANTES,AREA
AC,ACRELÂNDIA,12538,1807.92
AC,ASSIS BRASIL,6072,4974.18
AC,BRASILÉIA,21398,3916.5
AC,BUJARI,8471,3034.87
AL,BATALHA,17076,320.92
AL,BELÉM,4551,48.63
AM,BARCELOS,25718,122476.12
AM,BARREIRINHA,27355,5750.57
AM,BENJAMIN CONSTANT,33411,8793.42
```

Estou tentando somar apenas o número de habitantes da regiao norte, no caso, AC e AM. Para isso usei o código abaixo (em Python 3.6.5):

```
import csv

populacao = 0
arquivo = open('brasil.csv', encoding='utf8')
for registro in csv.reader(arquivo):
    habitantes = registro[2]
    estado = registro[0]
    if habitantes != 'habitantes':
        if estado != 'estado':
            regiao_norte = ['AC', 'AM']
            for estado in regiao_norte:
                populacao += int(habitantes)
print(populacao)
```

Obtenho como soma: 381511598. Mas a soma está claramente incorreta. Achei que o uso da lista atuaria como um selecionador dos estados que eu queria somar. Não consigo entender o que estou errando. Como posso fazer essa soma corretamente?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O teu erro, pelo menos o que salta mais à vista, é estares a percorrer cada estado do Norte em cada registo, que são dois, e a somar o número da habitantes dessa linha duas vezes. E isso acontece em todas as linhas (norte e outros) porque não estás a filtrar.

O modulo `csv` é desnecessário em grande parte dos casos que vejo, este é um deles, podes simplesmente fazer:

```
regiao_norte = {'AC', 'AM'}
populacao = 0
with open('brasil.csv') as f:
    f.readline() # ignorar o nome das colunas, so para evitar fazer operacoes desnecessarias em baixo sobre esta linha 
    for l in f: # percorrer cada linha do ficheiro
        vals = l.replace('\n', '').split(',') # tirar a quebra de linha e separar por virgula
        if(vals[0] in regiao_norte): 
            populacao += int(vals[2])
print(populacao) # 134963 para o exemplo colocado
```

Com o modulo csv:

```
import csv

regiao_norte = {'AC', 'AM'}
with open('brasil.csv') as f:
    populacao = sum(int(vals[2]) for vals in csv.reader(f) if vals[0] in regiao_norte)
print(populacao) # 134963 para o exemplo colocado
```

Para coisas mais sérias tens também um modulo massivamente usado, [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/), para este caso acho que não vale a pena, mas aqui está para o caso de pretenderes ir 'mais além' com esse dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('brasil.csv')
df_norte = df.loc[(df['ESTADO'] == 'AC') | (df['ESTADO'] == 'AM')] # linhas onde o estado for 'AM' ou 'AC'
populacao = df_norte['HABITANTES'].sum() # 134963 para o exemplo colocado
```

Comment: Obrigada pelas dicas, @Miguel , deram certo.

Comment: De nada @Alineat, bom estudo

Comment: No Pandas você conseguiria utilizar o operador `in`? Algo como `df.loc[df['ESTADO'] in ['AC', 'AM']]`

Comment: Olá @AndersonCarlosWoss, dsculpa mas só vi a pergunta agora. Infelizmente não, `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous`, https://repl.it/repls/BleakIllegalArchitects. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o